# How to use wildcards on numbers in an Advanced Filter (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have a table in an Excel sheet and I use Advanced filter to sort out data. One column of the table consists of number ID like this:

```
81089
81087
81009
81023
91087
91065
```

I found out that wildcards (*) doesn't work with numbers. Even if the numbers are formated as text. My question is how to make a simple filter where I would like to sort out numbers starting with 81 as `81*` doesn't work. From what I've read and found filtering numbers should work only with logic operators (< > =). Isn't there a trick how to get around with this?

Thanks for any answer in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use a mathematical equivalent.

For example, if all of your numbers are five digits, as you show in your screenshot, then

[image]

Another method is to use a text function as a formula criteria. Then the number of digits is irrelevant.

For example, if your first data element is in `A18`:

```
=LEFT(A18,2) = "81"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Both of them work well, allthough the most convenient I find creating a new column and converting the number with the 'TEXT' function and then using wildcards.